# How to add value in html table column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on the following codes. I need to add all the values per category in my table. The data is from the database. Please see the picture first:

[Here is my interface image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6pM5.jpg)

Here is my HTML codes:

```
<table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr align="center">
              <th width="5%">Item</th>
              <th width="30%">Description</th>
              <th width="5%">Unit</th>
              <th width="5%">Qty</th>
              <th width="10%">Unit Cost</th>
              <th width="15%">Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td colspan="5"><i>General Requirement</i></td>
              </tr>

              <?php  
              $id = $_GET['id'];
              $select_bill = "SELECT *, quantity * unit_cost AS amount FROM bill_tbl WHERE project_name = $id";
              $select_bill_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_bill);
              if (mysqli_num_rows($select_bill_result)> 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_bill_result)) {
                  if ($row['category'] == 'General Requirement') {
              ?>

              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['unit_cost']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                   }
                }
              }
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="4"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td colspan="5"><i>Concrete and Masonry Works</i></td>
              </tr>

              <?php  
              $id = $_GET['id'];
              $select_bill = "SELECT *, quantity * unit_cost AS amount FROM bill_tbl WHERE project_name = $id";
              $select_bill_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_bill);
              if (mysqli_num_rows($select_bill_result)> 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_bill_result)) {
                  if ($row['category'] == 'Concrete and Masonry Works') {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['unit_cost']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                   }
                }
              }
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="4"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
                <td></td>  
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Script code

```
<script>  
var total = 0;

var rows = $("#data tr:gt(0)");

rows.children("td:nth-child(6)").each(function() {
total += parseInt($(this).html());
});

$("#total").html(total);

</script>
```

This is for my school project.

Comment: The first one is 15000, the second one 74025. JK ;) Does this have to be done in Javascript?

Comment: Do you get some errors? Also, "gimme tha code" is not considered to be friendly here.

Comment: no errors, its just get the total sum at column 6. sorry bout asking for codes

Comment: Nobody do your homework. So you have to study and try something to reach your goal. So try to code and then ask here. Tip: don't calculate the total in js but calculate it via php

Comment: i have a code but i just don't know how to fix it. that is why i am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum it at PHP part. Code like this will sum all amounts while retrieving from DB.

```
<table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr align="center">
          <th width="5%">Item</th>
          <th width="30%">Description</th>
          <th width="5%">Unit</th>
          <th width="5%">Qty</th>
          <th width="10%">Unit Cost</th>
          <th width="15%">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="5"><i>General Requirement</i></td>
          </tr>

          <?php  
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          $select_bill = "SELECT *, quantity * unit_cost AS amount FROM bill_tbl WHERE project_name = $id";
          $select_bill_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_bill);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($select_bill_result)> 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_bill_result)) {
              if ($row['category'] == 'General Requirement') {

              $subtotal += $row['amount']; //Here you sum all amounts from rows
          ?>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit_cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
               }
            }
          }
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
            <td><?php echo $subtotal; //Here you display subtotal ?></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td colspan="5"><i>Concrete and Masonry Works</i></td>
          </tr>

          <?php  
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          $select_bill = "SELECT *, quantity * unit_cost AS amount FROM bill_tbl WHERE project_name = $id";
          $select_bill_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_bill);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($select_bill_result)> 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_bill_result)) {
              if ($row['category'] == 'Concrete and Masonry Works') {

              $subtotal += $row['amount']; //Here you sum all amounts from rows
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit_cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
               }
            }
          }
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
            <td><?php echo $subtotal; //Here you display subtotal ?></td>  
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr align="center">
          <th width="5%">Item</th>
          <th width="30%">Description</th>
          <th width="5%">Unit</th>
          <th width="5%">Qty</th>
          <th width="10%">Unit Cost</th>
          <th width="15%">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="5"><i>General Requirement</i></td>
          </tr>

          <?php  
          $id = $_GET['id']; $catA =0; //this variable will be use to get the some of the category. You can name the variable whatever name you want
          $select_bill = "SELECT *, quantity * unit_cost AS amount FROM bill_tbl WHERE project_name = $id";
          $select_bill_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_bill);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($select_bill_result)> 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_bill_result)) {
              if ($row['category'] == 'General Requirement') {
                $catA+=$row['amount']; // this will add each amount value to the $catA variable until the loop finished;
          ?>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit_cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
               }
            }
          }
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
            <td><?php echo $catA; //the variable now has the total sum of the amount;?></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td colspan="5"><i>Concrete and Masonry Works</i></td>
          </tr>

          <?php  
          $id = $_GET['id'];  $catB =0; //this variable will be use to get the some of the category. You can name the variable whatever name you want
          $select_bill = "SELECT *, quantity * unit_cost AS amount FROM bill_tbl WHERE project_name = $id";
          $select_bill_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_bill);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($select_bill_result)> 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_bill_result)) {
              if ($row['category'] == 'Concrete and Masonry Works') {
                 $catB+=$row['amount']; // this will add the amount value to the $catB variable until the loop finished; 
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit_cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
               }
            }
          }
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
            <td><?php echo $catB; //the variable now has the total sum of the amount;?></td>  
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```